# Thunderbird - Show all email addresses

Tags: thunderbird

I have a user who needs to show all of the email address in Thunderbird without having to click the "show triangle"!

To explain:- I have screenshotted before clicking the show triangle and after (email addresses removed to protect the innocent).  As you can see the second line of email addresses are hidden.

I imagine there is a setting in about:config, but I have yet to find it!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone did find a hack to enable something like this, but it seems like it could be more hassle than it's worth (and may not even work in the latest versions).

See this thread: http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=39&t=546398

You may want to add this as an idea at http://getsatisfaction.com/mozilla_messaging if it's not already there.

Answer (score 2):

Since Thunderbird 3.1.3 (circa 2010), the following property allows you to choose the default number of address lines shown before "more" appears:

```
mailnews.headers.show_n_lines_before_more
```

When equal to **0** all lines are shown. It defaults to **1**. ([Reference](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Mail_and_news_settings).)

Comment: This worked for me in Thunderbird 31.4.0.

Comment: Still works in Thunderbird 102. Thanks!